# Android Update Query

Tags: android, sqlite

I’m using a database helper to update a table with one row and two fields, I have the following code that that sends two phone numbers through.

```
dbHelper.updateNumbers(newSmsNumber, newVoiceNumber);
```

and the following method in the helper.

```
public void updateNumbers(String newSmsNumber, String newVoiceNumber) {

    //Update code here      
}
```

Can anyone show me the code I need to add in the method to update the two fields in the database.

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("SMS", newSmsNumber);
cv.put("Voice", newVoiceNumber);
db.update("[table name]", cv, "ID=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
```

There are some gaps to fill up though, the table name, and how you identify the entry you want to update (I put a "ID" field there in that example)

Did not run that code, did not really check, but that should give you an idea.

Comment: I had it pretty close, the first three lines were exactly what I needed but the way I had my helper set up the fourth line that works for me is: getWritableDatabase().update("numbers", cv, null, null);

Comment: Because there is no _id field, the table contains only one record with two fields, there is never more than one row, if you know what I mean. cheers,

Comment: In that case, I am not really sure why you use a database... Could use some shared preference or something like that, but that's completely up to you. Glad this helped.

Comment: I was unaware there were other ways to store up-datable data apart from a database? The numbers will probably never change so could be hard coded. In my experience though, you need to cover all bases.